# change radio button state when parent is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, radio-button

I have this markup :

```
<div class='A'>
    <input type='radio' name='B' class='B' />
</div>
<div class='A'>
    <input type='radio' name='B' class='B' />
</div>
<div class='A'>
    <input type='radio' name='B' class='B' />
</div>
```

The desired functionality is to select the radio either by clicking parent `div` or the radio input itself and if the radio is already checked then click on parent will have no effect i.e return false.

I have made it to change on click of parent, but when i click on the radio button , nothing happens.
What's wrong with my approach ?

jQuery :

```
$('input:radio').closest('div').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($('input:radio', this).prop('checked') === true) {
        console.log("returning false");
        return false;
    }
    $('input:radio', this).prop('checked', true);
    console.log("Clicked : " + $(this).attr('class'));
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pSSc9/1/

Comment: just remove `return false;` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/pSSc9/6/ you need to understand that `return false` means, `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()`, so you're stopping both. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.A').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('.B')) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        // So that event does not bubble when radio is selected
    } else {
        if ($('input:radio', this).prop('checked') === true) {
            console.log("returning false");
            return false;
        }
        $('input:radio', this).prop('checked', true);
    }
    console.log("Clicked : " + $(e.target).attr('class'));
});
```

The problem with your code was you were returning false when the checkbox is clicked. So you were indirectly doing `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` by doing `return false;`

You explicitly need to set the checked property to true only when clicked on the div. But when you click on the radio it performs the default action. So you need to stop the propagation of the event.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/pSSc9/5/)**

Comment: What's wrong with this   `$('input:radio').closest('div').on('click'...)` ?

Comment: @user2516522.. Check edited code.. There was nothing wrong with the selector..  I used `.A` as the div can be directly selected using a class.

Comment: I am still not able to check radio button by directly clicking on it

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest using `label` elements instead of `div`s? You'll get the same behavior and won't need javascript at all. CSS will take care of the appearance. I made that simple change in your fiddle, and it worked fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/jeffman/WQEDv/2/

Comment: Jeffman's answer is the right one. It works beautifully. You don't need JavaScript then.

Comment: Alternately, you can just wrap the existing `div`s in `label`s, and since `labels` are inline, they will conform to fit the `div` exactly.

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/pSSc9/3/)

`e.preventDefault();` disables the `radio` button `click` event

```
$('input:radio').closest('div').on('click', function (e) {
    $('input:radio', this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: @user2516522 any reason for you to return false?

Comment: yes. i don't want the ajax call to be fired if radio is already checked.. i do have ajax call further in the callback..that i havent posted here

Answer (score 1):

The `click` event from the radio button is bubbling up to the `div`, so the callback gets triggered in both cases. The problem is that you're preventing the default action which, in the case of the radio button, is it becoming checked.

What you can do is add a condition that exits the callback if the element clicked was the radio button:

```
$('input:radio').closest('div').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('input')) {
        return;
    }

    if ($('input:radio', this).prop('checked') === true) {
        console.log("returning false");
        return false;
    }
    $('input:radio', this).prop('checked', true);
    console.log("Clicked : " + $(this).attr('class'));
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/pSSc9/4/)

Comment: if you click on radio directly.. it does select the radio.. but then the function will not execute further due to `return` call.....What do you think ?

Comment: If you need to do other things in the function and not return right away, just be mindful of not preventing default or returning `false` if `e.target` is the input.